# Fusion infowindow output adding "\n" and geolocation

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've been working on this for a couple so getting to this point should make me very happy. However, I cannot figure out my infowindow output is adding "\n" to every new line. No idea how it's getting there. The geolocation is also being appended to the search result infowindow. I'd like to remove that as well.

Here is a link to the map: http://58design.com/gmaps/

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Sheriff | Zone Leader Look Up</title>

    <meta name="author" content="Santa Clarita Valley Sheriff" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2013 SCV Sheriff" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Santa Clarita Valley Sheriff, SCV Sheriff, Canyon Country, Valencia, Saugus, Newhall, Castaic, Gorman, Stevenson Ranch, " />
    <meta name="description" content="Santa Clarita Valley Sheriff Zone Leader Contact Inforamtion Look Up." />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="Googlebot" content="follow" />
    <meta name="googlebot" content="archive" />
    <meta name="distribution" content="global" />

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});

    //var FusionTableID = 1931355;
    var FusionTableID = '1uSGM1yPMJBlu74Znm4fPqdCsJjteB_kQ_nGz3tk';
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = null;
    var infowindow = null;
    var marker = null;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({size: new google.maps.Size(150,50) });
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.452789398370045, -118.51948001245114),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

  //layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FusionTableID,{suppressInfoWindows:true});
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col2",
        from: "1uSGM1yPMJBlu74Znm4fPqdCsJjteB_kQ_nGz3tk",
        where: "",
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
  layer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e) {
    var content = e.row['description'].value+"<br><br>";
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
    });

}
function showAddress(address) {
    var contentString = address+"<br>Outside Area";

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var point = results[0].geometry.location;
          contentString += "<br>"+point;
          map.setCenter(point);
          if (marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: point
          });
          // query FT for data
          var queryText ="SELECT 'description', 'Zone Area'  FROM "+FusionTableID+" WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(\'Zone Area\', CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + point.toUrlValue(6) + "),0.5));";
          // document.getElementById('FTQuery').innerHTML = queryText;
          queryText = encodeURIComponent(queryText);
          var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

          //set the callback function
          query.send(openInfoWindowOnMarker);

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
}

function openInfoWindowOnMarker(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
  var content = "<b>Outside area</b><br><br>";    
  var unionBounds = null;
//  alert(numRows);
  for (var i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
     var name = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(i,0);
     var kml =  FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(i,1);
     content = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,0)+"<br><br>";
   }
  infowindow.setContent(content+marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
  // zoom to the bounds
  // map.fitBounds(unionBounds);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
            <div id="content">
                <h1>SCV Sheriff Reporting Zones</h1>
                <p>Use the map below to determine your area's Zone Leader. Enter your street address, city and zip code in the search field below to view the Zone Leader's contact info.</p>

                <form action="#" onsubmit="showAddress(this.address.value); return false" style="padding:10px 0px 30px 0px; background:none;">                      
                    <label>Address Search</label>
                    <input type="text" size="60" name="address" value="23920 Valencia Blvd. Santa Clarita, CA 91355" class="address" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                    </p>
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 516px; height: 387px; margin-bottom:30px; border:1px solid #999;"></div>                    
                </form>

            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
            </div>
            <div class="clear"><!--clear--></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the data in your FusionTable (the line feeds are getting translated into "\n").  I fixed the entry for "Gorman" in [my example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_geocodedQuery.html) (by removing the extraneous line feeds).

This line of my code is appending the geolocation to the search result infowindow:

```
infowindow.setContent(content+marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
```